# Jquery link to an an external webpage

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following code.

```
<script type="text/JavaScript">
// prepare the form when the DOM is ready 
$(document).ready(function() {
var galleryClass = '.gallery';
$(galleryClass+' li img').click(function(){
    var $gallery = $(this).parents(galleryClass);
    $('.main-img',$gallery).attr('src',$(this).attr('src').replace('thumb/', ''))
    .parent().attr('href',$(this).parent().attr('href'));
});
var imgSwap = [];
 $(galleryClass+' li img').each(function(){
    imgUrl = this.src.replace('thumb/', '');
    imgSwap.push(imgUrl);
});
$(imgSwap).preload();
});
$.fn.preload = function() {
this.each(function(){
    $('<img/>')[0].src = this;
});

}
</script>
```

The following HTML code.

```
<div class="gallery">
<img src="gallery/img_1.png" alt="" class="main-img" />
<img src="images/Select-Brands.jpg" width="1010" height="50" />
<ul>
  <li><img src="gallery/thumb/img_1.png" alt="" /></li>
  <li><img src="gallery/thumb/img_2.png" alt="" /></li>
  <li><img src="gallery/thumb/img_3.png" alt="" /></li>
  <li><img src="gallery/thumb/img_4.png" alt="" /></li>
  <li><img src="gallery/thumb/img_5.png" alt="" /></li>
  <li><img src="gallery/thumb/img_6.png" alt="" /></li>
  <li><img src="gallery/thumb/img_7.png" alt="" /></li>
  <li><img src="gallery/thumb/img_8.png" alt="" /></li>
  <li><img src="gallery/thumb/img_9.png" alt="" /></li>

</ul>
</div>
```

This is the site example.
http://flairnecessities.com/AskarBrands/askarbrands.html
When you click on each logo it brings up a new image. I would like to have each large image (8 of them) go to 8 separate external websites. They also need to open a separate window.

What is the code that is needed to do this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry read the question fast.

```
<ul>
  <li><img rel="http://www.google.com" src="http://flairnecessities.com/AskarBrands/gallery/thumb/img_1.png" alt="" /></li>
  <li><img rel="http://www.google.com" src="http://flairnecessities.com/AskarBrands/gallery/thumb/img_2.png" alt="" /></li>
  <li><img rel="http://www.google.com" src="http://flairnecessities.com/AskarBrands/gallery/thumb/img_3.png" alt="" /></li>
  <li><img rel="http://www.google.com" src="http://flairnecessities.com/AskarBrands/gallery/thumb/img_4.png" alt="" /></li>
  <li><img rel="http://www.google.com" src="http://flairnecessities.com/AskarBrands/gallery/thumb/img_5.png" alt="" /></li>
  <li><img rel="http://www.google.com" src="http://flairnecessities.com/AskarBrands/gallery/thumb/img_6.png" alt="" /></li>
  <li><img rel="http://www.google.com" src="http://flairnecessities.com/AskarBrands/gallery/thumb/img_7.png" alt="" /></li>
  <li><img rel="http://www.google.com" src="http://flairnecessities.com/AskarBrands/gallery/thumb/img_8.png" alt="" /></li>
  <li><img rel="http://www.google.com" src="http://flairnecessities.com/AskarBrands/gallery/thumb/img_9.png" alt="" /></li>

</ul>
```

add a rel tag defining the url of each thumbnail (above):

add this wrapper around you main image link:

```
<a id ="linker" href="#" target="_blank"><img src="http://flairnecessities.com/AskarBrands/gallery/img_1.png" alt="" class="main-img" /></a>
```

finally add this to your initial click function:

```
var link = $(this).attr('rel');
$('#linker').attr('href',link);
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment Jay. Doing it that way actually makes the smaller logo (the ones in the bar) link to the external web page and not the larger image above. I want when you click on the smaller logos that they change the larger picture above and when you click on the larger picture it takes you to that company's website.

Answer (score 1):

HTML

```
<img src="img.png" data-lg="large.png" data-href="http://google.com">
<a class="lg-link"><img class"img-lg"></a>
```

jQuery

```
$("[data-lg]").click(function(){
  $(".img-lg").attr("src", $(this).data("lg"));
  $(".lg-link").attr("href", $(this).data("href"));
});
```

CSS

```
[data-lg]{
  cursor:pointer;
}
```